# Shared config and functions between frontend / backend (e.g. AngularJS / Django)

Tags: django, angularjs, rest, frontend, backend

The question can be general, but suppose that Django is used to provide RESTful APIs consumed by an application written in AngularJS.

Both applications need some configuration variables, some of those shared between the two. For example, both of them need to know the list of holidays of the current year. For Django, one can write this list in the `settings.py` file or as a constant in the `Model` class. For AngularJS, it is possible to write a `Service` or a `Factory` that can be dependency injected where needed.

How to avoid this duplication? That is, how do I write the list a single time?
Instead of hard coding the variables in an AngularJS Factory, they can be loaded via an Ajax request, as the application is loaded on the client, that is as the `Factory` is created.

A second option can be a JSON file that can be parsed in Django and loaded in AngularJS.

Which is the customary way?

What about functions? Suppose that in the AngularJS application I have a cart with a function that calculates in real time, as I tweak the content of the cart, the total price based on objects, quantities, and whatever complex relations one can think of. I don't want to make an Ajax request to ask the backend for the computation of the total price.

I finally send the content of the cart to the backend via the RESTful API I created with Django. Of course I don't want to send the total price in the call (the user could send any total price), but I want to calculate it again from the backend side.

Are there any options to write the function to calculate the total price only once?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to store your functions as javascript, and use V8 engine to interpret javascript server side.

This blog post describes it: http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/23/sharing-simple-business-logic-between-the-client-and-front-end-with-rails/